Google Sign-In with Drive Scopes Fails with "Invalid Scope" on Certain Android TVs
I am working on a project that integrates Google Sign-In with Google Drive access using the following code:
GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions =
    new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)     
    .requestEmail()
    .requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE), new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA))
    .build();

The code was previously working across all Android TV devices. However, recently, it stopped working on certain devices. Here are the issues I am facing on different TV models :
NVIDIA Shield Android TV

OS version: 11
Google Play Services version: 24.49.61
Issue:

Prompts the user to choose an account.
After account selection, sign-in fails, and Logcat shows the message : Invalid scope for Drive.



Sony Bravia TV (Model: KDL-48W800F)

OS version: 9
Google Play Services version: 24.49.61
Issue:

Prompts the user to choose an account.

After account selection, sign-in fails, and Logcat shows the message : Invalid scope for Drive .




Here are the TV models on which Google Sign-In works.
Sony Bravia TV (Model: Bravia VU3)

OS version: 11
Prompts the user to choose an account.
Displays the Google Drive permission prompt.
Successfully gets access to Google Drive after granting permission.

Google TV emulator  & Android TV emulator

OS version : 12

Prompts the user to choose an account.

Display the Google Drive permission prompt

Successfully gets access to Google Drive after granting permission


If I comment out .requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE), new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA)), Google Sign-In works.
I tried updating the dependency
Dependencies used in the project:
build.gradle (Module level)
build.gradle (Project level)

OAuth 2.0 for TV and Limited-Input Device Applications

This document explains how to implement OAuth 2.0 authorization to
access Google APIs via applications running on devices like TVs, game
consoles, and printers. More specifically, this flow is designed for
devices that either do not have access to a browser or have limited
input capabilities.

Read more
Also you can review the Allowed Scopes for the Drive API.

[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file]
Create new Drive files, or modify existing files, that you open with an app or that the user shares with an app while using the Google Picker API or the app's file picker.

[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata]
View and manage the app's own configuration data in your Google Drive.



For the same above mentioned code ,now sign-in working after refactoring the TV device ,Why is it and what was affecting that for the failure ?
